# How to paste columns from multiple files in an orderly way?

Tags: file, multiple-columns, bash

I've got a output with different file names: file_1.dat..file_15.dat

I'm using this command:

```
paste result_*.dat | column -s $'\t' -t >> cache/Final_Evolution.dat
```

But my output files are sorted in this way and I don't know why:

```
file_1.dat
file_11.dat
file_13.dat
file_15.dat
file_3.dat
file_5.dat
file_7.dat
file_9.dat
```

So, when I use the command mentioned, the order of the data columns is 1, 11, 13 ... when I want 1,3,5,7 ...

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Normalize the file names. `for f in file_?.dat ; do mv "$f" "${f/_/_0}" ; done`

Comment: @choroba YES!!!. That works! Thank youuuuuuuu very much.

Comment: This is occurring due to ordering of linux glob pattern(alphabetic sort). Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38317/glob-with-numerical-order

Comment: @choroba, You should post your comment as an answer... maybe expound on what/how `"${f/_/_0}"` does/works.  I'd up-vote it for sure.

Comment: @choroba Is there any way to change second ( "low bar") instead of the first. I mean, for example file_data_1 -> file_data_01. 

I have done what you said but replace the first "_" giving rise to: file_0data_1

Comment: @Enrique: What are the actual file names? The exact solution depends on details.

Comment: @choroba From `distances_files_1.dat.results.dat.splits` to `distances_files_15.dat.results.dat.splits`

Comment: OK, then you can use `for f in distances_files_?.dat.results.dat.splits ; do mv "$f" "${f/_files_/_files_0}" ; done`

Comment: @choroba YES!, That works! Thank you again ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalize the filenames first.

```
for f in file_?.dat ; do
    mv "$f" "${f/_/_0}"
done
```

It replaces `_` by `_0` in all the files with single-digit numbers (`?` matches a single character).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way with `sort`, you can do it as

```
sort -t _ -k 2 -g cache/Final_Evolution.dat
```

where `-t` for de-limiting with `_` and `-k 2` for second column after de-limiting (which is the numbers column) and `-g` for numerical sort.

```
file_1.dat
file_3.dat
file_5.dat
file_7.dat
file_9.dat
file_11.dat
file_13.dat
file_15.dat
```

Comment: `sort -V` is helpful here, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the files as pointed out in the comments or use a glob like this:

```
paste file_?.dat file_??.dat
```

`?` will expand to exactly one charcter, so `file_?.dat` can only expand to: `file_1.dat` .. `file_9.dat` and `file_??.dat` can only expand to `file_10.dat` ..  `file_99.dat`.

This will however fail if you have no files matching the glob as it will be treated literately.